# Create count loop

Tags: javascript

I have come across this problem and embarassed to say I have never devised a good solution that has left me feeling satisfied -

I want to count to a number and then once the number is reached start counting up from 0 again.

so in JavaScript, we might have

```
var incr = 0;

if (incr === 50) {
    incr = 0;
}
incr++;
```

is there a more elegant way to do that, or is this pretty much the only way to do it? I keep thinking there is a way to do it with Math.max or Math.min, but never have figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use mod by 50

```
incr %= 50
```

Answer (score 1):

Use modulus `%` for this.

```
incr++ % 50;
```

Comment: I don't know about JS but in Java this will not work: you have to store result of it like: incr = (incr++) % 50, but in this case incr will always be 0, since incr++ applies after expression calculation

Answer (score -1):

Dont know if this counts. But a simple for and while loop?

```
var targetNumber = 50;
while(true) // Some condition
{
    for (var i = 0; i < targetNumber; i++)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```